# Find duplicates in Pandas DataFrame and update a value with previous row/column entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find duplicates on a subset of a Pandas Dataframe. Where there is duplication I need to update a value with the previous row's column entry.

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {'day': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
       'id': ['2021-01', '2021-01', '2021-02', 'xyz', '2021-09', 
              '2021-09', 'abc', '2021-08', '2021-01'],
       'p1': [1,1,1,2,3,9,6,12,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

    day id  p1
0   Mon 2021-01 1
1   Tue 2021-01 1
2   Wed 2021-02 1
3   Wed xyz     2
4   Thu 2021-09 3
5   Fri 2021-09 9
6   Fri abc     6
7   Sat 2021-08 12
8   Sun 2021-01 3
```

In the above simplified example I wish to find duplicate "day" entries then update the last entry "id" value with the fist entry "id" value.

For Example index 3 "id" becomes index 2 "id" etc.:

```
    day id  p1
0   Mon 2021-01 1
1   Tue 2021-01 1
2   Wed 2021-02 1
3   Wed 2021-02 2
4   Thu 2021-09 3
5   Fri 2021-09 9
6   Fri 2021-09 6
7   Sat 2021-08 12
8   Sun 2021-01 3
```

I can do this using `df.iterrows()` but feel this is not the best approach as I have considerably large datasets.

I have attempted using a `df.duplicated()` and the first and last "keep" property to set the new values but get warnings:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

This code produces the warning:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['day'],keep='last')]['id'] = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['day'],keep='first')]['id']
```

How can I achieve this result without encountering this type of warning whilst not using iterrows?

Comment: the reason for the warning is the use of ['id'] at the end of the loc, you can select the column you want in the loc instead of out of it (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['day'],keep='last'), 'id'] = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['day'],keep='first'), 'id']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `mask` and `ffill`. For `duplicated` you need to keep the first (i.e. mark the other ones as duplicated).

```
m = df['day'].duplicated()
df['id'] = df['id'].mask(m).ffill()
```

output:

```
    day       id  p1
0   Mon  2021-01   1
1   Tue  2021-01   1
2   Wed  2021-02   1
3   Wed  2021-02   2
4  Thur  2021-09   3
5   Fri  2021-09   9
6   Fri  2021-09   6
7   Sat  2021-08  12
8   Sun  2021-01   3
```

Comment: Please let me know if the below code works the same as your code : df1 = df.groupby(['day'], as_index=False).first()             .............df1 = df.merge(df1,on = 'day',how='left')                       ........df1.rename(columns={'id_y':'id','p1_x':'p1'},inplace = True) 
                    ............df1 =df1[['day','id','p1']]

Comment: @Anil doesn't seem to work at all, why don't you suggest your own answer? ;)